# Equivalence of trend stationary process and stationary process

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, stochastic-processes, autoregressive, trend

I am new to Time Series, and I am having some trouble dealing with the constant of an AR(p) process, which of course 'reinforces' itself over time to become a deterministic trend.

For simplicity sake, say we have a AR(1) process, $$y_{t}=\alpha_{0}+\alpha_{1}y_{t-1}+\epsilon_{t}\;(*)$$ such that $(\epsilon_{t})_{t}$ is white noise $WN(0,\sigma^{2})$ and $\alpha_{0},\alpha_{1}$ some constants. In our lectures, we simply stated that we can transform the trend stationary model $(*)$ into a stationary model by subtracting $\alpha_{0}$ which delivers the model:

$$y_{t}-\alpha_{0}=\alpha_{1}y_{t-1}+\epsilon_{t}.$$

I do not find this to be immediately clear or trivial. Are we referring to the process $\tilde{y_{t}}:=y_{t}-\alpha_{0}$ that is stationary? In general, I am rather confused about the inclusion of a constant/trend since all examples I have seen are without such terms. Why are the two model types equivalent?

Comment: Subtracting $\alpha_0$ does not do anything meaningful. You should subtract the long run mean $\mu = \frac{\alpha_0}{1-\alpha_1}$ from $(*)$.
This tells you that $(*)$ implies $\bar{y}_t = \alpha_1 \bar{y}_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$ where $\bar{y}_t = y_t - \mu$ is deviation from long run mean. In other words, if $y_t$ follows an AR(1) with intercept, then its deviation from long run mean is an AR(1) with no intercept. They are not equivalent, but in many cases it's enough to model deviation from long run mean and in such cases you can restrict yourself to models with no intercept.